# Number of partitions of $n$ with Durfee square of size $k$

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

> Show that the number of partitions of $n$ with [Durfee square](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DurfeeSquare.html) of size k is $\leq \dfrac{n^{2k}}{(k!)^2}$

I've thought it's equivalent to the number of partitions of $n$ such that $k$ of the numbers are $\geq k$ and the rest of them $\leq k$,
which is equivalent to the number of partitions of $n-k^2$ such that $k$ of the numbers are $\geq 0$ and the rest are $\leq k$.
I got stuck in getting from that to the requested bound.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the parts below the Durfee square.  Each of these parts is at most $k$ and there are at most $n$ parts, so they contribute at most $\frac{n^k}{k!}$, where we've divided by the $k!$ possible reorderings.

Parts to the right of the Durfee square may be bounded analogously.  Thus, together, we get a bound of $$\left(\frac{n^k}{k!}\right)^2.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if you divide by $k!$ doesn't it give a lower bound instead of an upper bound? For example, if all the parts are identical then you don't have to divide

Comment: I did not quite understand your answer. Could you please explain why dividing $n^k$ by $k!$ guarantees we are still upper-bounding the number of partitions of n with Durfee square of size k?